# Transferring Interger once a game has started GameKit

Tags: game-center, multiplayer, gamekit, swift5

I have successfully used the Apple Documentation to connect two players via Game Center and start the game. However, I have been struggling for days at getting the app to send data between two players.

I just need to send an integer between the two players but can't even get the documentation code to run, even after creating the structs etc. Examples I have looked at already are dated or I can't get them to build.

```
func sendPosition() {

let messageToSend = 123

//what do I need to do messageToSend to send it?

    do {
        try match.sendData(toAllPlayers: packet, with: .unreliable)
    } catch {
    }

    if error != nil {

        // Handle the error.
    }

}

    func match(_ match: GKMatch, didReceive data: Data, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer) {
       //What do I need to do to receive the data?

       }
```

If anyone can help with some working code I can experiment with in Swift 5+ I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading and playing my original code seemed to work!!! If it helps anyone else:

To send:

```
@IBAction func sendDataBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    print("sending data")
    let dataString = "Hello, World!"
    let dataToSend = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
    do {
    try myMatch.sendData(toAllPlayers: dataToSend!, with: .reliable)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

To receive:

```
func match(_ match: GKMatch, didReceive data: Data, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer) {
    print("Data Received")
    let receivedData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    messageLbl.text = receivedData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a 'container' to send over data, this way I can add an instruction and what needs to be done in one go. For example;

```
    var type:String = "jump"
    var data:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:10,y:10)
    
    let container:[Any] = [type, data]

    
do {
      let dataToSend = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: container, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try match.sendData(toAllPlayers: packet, with: .unreliable)
    } catch {
    }

    if error != nil {

        // Handle the error.
    }
```